# How to create a map file (with links to project files) in Intellij Javadoc

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hyperlink, javadoc, intellij-plugin

I need to have a simple file that will just maps some of my project files and I can click on a link and open a file.

Here is an example

```
/**
 *  <a href="./src/java/SomeFileName.java">Here the magic begins</a>
 */
```

But I am not able to click on a link to open the file.

Is there any way to do this, I don't need it to be a java or any specific file, just that it should be possible to click on a link and open a file.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I've also tried

```
<a href="H:\Development\Java\Projects\SuperProjecct\src\SomeFileName.txt">Here the magic begins</a>

<a href="file:///H:\Development\Java\Projects\SuperProjecct\src\SomeFileName.txt">Here the magic begins</a>
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/26632551/104891 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/43772805/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder as you could see I am already using the solution from that answers. And it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work because JavaDoc doesn't support relative paths and you have to use full paths instead?

Comment: @CrazyCoder, thank you for response I've just update my question. Doesn't work either (